# How to run .sh file from console

Tags: python, powershell, shell

I would like to know why I can not run the `.sh` file via `./launch.sh`
please have a look at the below posted screen-shot

**image**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark it as an executable program with `chmod +x launch.sh`, or alternatively execute it with bash: `bash launch.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I think the command  would be sh launch.sh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@Wouter De Coster solve the problem, anyway i´ll try to add a bit more information.

## Console Method

### Setting Area

To use `./` function, the file must have execute permission on the script.

use `chmod +x launch.sh` to set that permissions.

### Run Area

Try to use `./launch.sh` again.

Another options to execute them:

`sh launch.sh`

`bash launch.sh`

## GUI Method

### Setting Area

1. Select the file using mouse
2. Right-click on the file
3. Choose properties

[image: Properties actions]

4. Click **Permissions** tab
5. Select Allow executing file as a program:

[image: Properties functions]

### Run Area

Click the file name and you will be prompted. Select `Run in the terminal` and it will get executed in the terminal.

Once you changed the properties you can use the **Run methods** used in **Console Method**

#EXTRA

You can run .sh file and use debugging options, For example:

To debug shell script. It print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

`bash -x launch.sh`

To show shell input lines as they are read:

`bash -v launch.sh`